# Problems opening .xlsx file created with EPPlus and zipped in a folder with ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib

Tags: c#, asp.net, xlsx, epplus, sharpziplib

I am creating a list of ExcelPackages (xlsx documents) using EPPlus, and adding them to a ZipOutputStream as ZipEntries. I think the Excel documents should be valid, as I can open them just fine when I write one of them to the Response object without zipping.
The zip folder is created as expected, and the file(s) are there and doesnt seem to be empty, but when I try to open them I get the following error in Excel:

> Excel cannot open the file {Name}.xlsx because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file

```
List<ExcelPackage> documents = new List<ExcelPackage>();
List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();

//Code for fetching documents and filenames here (removed for the sake of readability)

Response.Clear();
Context.Response.BufferOutput = false; 
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"random-foldername.zip\"");
Response.CacheControl = "Private";
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3)); 

ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(Response.OutputStream);
zipOutputStream.SetLevel(3); //0-9, 9 being the highest level of compression
byte[] buffer = null;

for (int i = 0; i < documents.Count; i++)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    documents[i].SaveAs(ms);

    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(ZipEntry.CleanName(fileNames[i]));

    zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
    buffer = new byte[ms.Length];

    ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    entry.Size = ms.Length;

    ms.Close();

    zipOutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    zipOutputStream.CloseEntry();

}
zipOutputStream.Finish();
zipOutputStream.Close();

Response.End();
```

As for the list of filenames, im just generating a name based on some arbitrary stuff and adding a ".xlsx"-extension to the end of it.

Im not sure where im going wrong here, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to rewind memory stream before you can read something (after write operation file pointer is that its end):

```
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

That said a `MemoryStream` is nothing more than a byte array so you don't even need to allocate and read a new one then this code:

```
buffer = new byte[ms.Length];

ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
entry.Size = ms.Length;

ms.Close();

zipOutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Can be simply replaced with:

```
entry.Size = ms.Length;
zipOutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.Length);
ms.Close();
```

Final note: if you don't want to use internal `MemoryStream` buffer (for any reason) and you want a trimmed copy of it (as you're doing manually) then simply use `ToArray()` method like this:

```
var buffer = ms.ToArray();
ms.Close();
entry.Size = buffer.Length;
zipOutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Comment: You sir, are a genious. Weird thing I havent seen that code in any samples yet, as I've been googling the crap out of this issue before posting here.

Comment: @HansPetterNaumann Unfortunately I'm not...I just forgot to Seek the stream too many times...

Comment: Well, then I hope I will remember it next time. Nevertheless, thanks alot!